# In mongodb cluster, Can I shut down one config server and one data server in the shard at the same time

Tags: mongodb, clustering, upgrade, configuration

I have one mongodb cluster, including 3 config servers, and one shard (3 data servers in this shard). One data server and one config server are on the same machine. Can I shut both of them down to upgrade the cluster without stop the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal rules of [replica set elections](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-elections/) apply.

If your shard is backed by a 3-node replica set, then you can have any single node down while still being able to maintain a primary. A strict majority of nodes must be available, so 2/3 in the 3-node example.

If the data-bearing server you are planning to restart happens to be a replica set primary, I would shut it down gracefully with [`db.shutdownServer()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.shutdownServer/) to minimise down time (and make sure there is an eligible secondary whose oplog data is within 10 seconds of the primary). `db.shutdownServer()` runs the [`shutdown` command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/shutdown/#dbcmd.shutdown) against the `admin` database.

Comment: Can I show down one config server and one data server in the replication set **at the same time**?

Comment: Yes, you can do this. As noted, if you want to maintain availability in your replica set the normal rules for election apply (i.e. have a majority of nodes available).

Comment: Please note that running a config server and a data bearing node in one instance is discouraged and that shutting down a config server prevents chunk splits and migrations, which might lead to the dreaded, non-movable jumbo chunks.